# How to list integer field of distinct values in ascending order in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

I am using django as backend and PostgresSql as DB. One problem I'm getting is sorting the distinct values in ascending order.

I Have Distinct values in filter as:

16,14,4,64,8,6,12,10,18,2,32,24

now i want those values as

2,4,6,8,10.......

I have code like this to get those distinct values

`filter_cores = Processor.objects.distinct().values('cores')`

HOW I CAN DO IN ASCENDING ORDER?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order_by`, refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

```
Processor.objects.distinct().values('cores').order_by('cores')
```

Comment: Nothing happening just scrambled all the data thats it